# jersey restful + grizzly server + hibernate

Tags: hibernate, rest, webserver, jersey, grizzly

I can bring jersey + grizzly server up. But some problem occur during "SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory;"
error says "SEVERE: service exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found

.. anyone know how to make hibernate can access hibernate.cfg.xml location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in the 'src/main/resources' directory of your project.  Also, if you've specified "/hibernate.cfg.cml", try removing the slash so it reads "hibernate.cfg.xml"

If that doesn't work (no directory, classpath wrong, etc...) you can hardcode it to get it working.

```
File f = new File("/wherever/the/file/is/hibernate.cfg.xml"); 
sessions = new Configuration().configure(f).buildSessionFactory();
```

Then circle back later and repay your technical debt.